# Compile external class against jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have a binary jar file called : prog.jar
I also have an external class that I created called : eval.java
I'm trying to compile the java file eval with the jar file prog.jar so I could use some of the methods in prog. I do the following:

```
javac -cp prog.jar eval.java
java -cp .;prog.jar eval
```

Once I run the command I get the following error:
-bash: /Users/joe/prog.jar: cannot execute binary file

Any suggestions about what might be going on wrong with what Im doing?

Comment: What are you trying to do? do you use a ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec to run prog.jar? Note that you have a space in your classpath between the `;` and `prog.jar`. this needs to be removed, i.e. `java -cp .;prog.jar eval`

Comment: I run prog.jar using the following command: java -jar prog.jar